# MySQL GROUP BY two columns

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm trying to group by multiple columns here - one on each table.
It's a scenario where I want to find the top portfolio value for each client by adding their current portfolio and cash together but a client may have more than one portfolio, so I need the top portfolio for each client.

At the moment, with the code below I'm getting the same clients multiple times for each of their top portfolios (it's not grouping by client id).

```
SELECT clients.id, clients.name, portfolios.id, SUM ( portfolios.portfolio +  portfolios.cash ) AS total
FROM clients, portfolios
WHERE clients.id = portfolios.client_id
GROUP BY portfolios.id, clients.id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

First, let's make some test data:

```
create table client (client_id integer not null primary key auto_increment,
                     name varchar(64));
create table portfolio (portfolio_id integer not null primary key auto_increment,
                        client_id integer references client.id,
                        cash decimal(10,2),
                        stocks decimal(10,2));
insert into client (name) values ('John Doe'), ('Jane Doe');
insert into portfolio (client_id, cash, stocks) values (1, 11.11, 22.22),
                                                       (1, 10.11, 23.22),
                                                       (2, 30.30, 40.40),
                                                       (2, 40.40, 50.50);
```

If you didn't need the portfolio ID, it would be easy:

```
select client_id, name, max(cash + stocks)
from client join portfolio using (client_id)
group by client_id

+-----------+----------+--------------------+
| client_id | name     | max(cash + stocks) |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+
|         1 | John Doe |              33.33 | 
|         2 | Jane Doe |              90.90 | 
+-----------+----------+--------------------+
```

Since you need the portfolio ID, things get more complicated.  Let's do it in steps.  First, we'll write a subquery that returns the maximal portfolio value for each client:

```
select client_id, max(cash + stocks) as maxtotal
from portfolio
group by client_id

+-----------+----------+
| client_id | maxtotal |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |    33.33 | 
|         2 |    90.90 | 
+-----------+----------+
```

Then we'll query the portfolio table, but use a join to the previous subquery in order to keep only those portfolios the total value of which is the maximal for the client:

```
 select portfolio_id, cash + stocks from portfolio 
 join (select client_id, max(cash + stocks) as maxtotal 
       from portfolio
       group by client_id) as maxima
 using (client_id)
 where cash + stocks = maxtotal

+--------------+---------------+
| portfolio_id | cash + stocks |
+--------------+---------------+
|            5 |         33.33 | 
|            6 |         33.33 | 
|            8 |         90.90 | 
+--------------+---------------+
```

Finally, we can join to the client table (as you did) in order to include the name of each client:

```
select client_id, name, portfolio_id, cash + stocks
from client
join portfolio using (client_id)
join (select client_id, max(cash + stocks) as maxtotal
      from portfolio 
      group by client_id) as maxima
using (client_id)
where cash + stocks = maxtotal

+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| client_id | name     | portfolio_id | cash + stocks |
+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|         1 | John Doe |            5 |         33.33 | 
|         1 | John Doe |            6 |         33.33 | 
|         2 | Jane Doe |            8 |         90.90 | 
+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Note that this returns two rows for John Doe because he has two portfolios with the exact same total value.  To avoid this and pick an arbitrary top portfolio, tag on a GROUP BY clause:

```
select client_id, name, portfolio_id, cash + stocks
from client
join portfolio using (client_id)
join (select client_id, max(cash + stocks) as maxtotal
      from portfolio 
      group by client_id) as maxima
using (client_id)
where cash + stocks = maxtotal
group by client_id, cash + stocks

+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| client_id | name     | portfolio_id | cash + stocks |
+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|         1 | John Doe |            5 |         33.33 | 
|         2 | Jane Doe |            8 |         90.90 | 
+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: That's an amazing answer, and once I'd put ORDER BY maxtotal DESC on the end it's perfect! ;)
Thank you

Answer (score 106):

Using Concat on the group by will work

```
SELECT clients.id, clients.name, portfolios.id, SUM ( portfolios.portfolio + portfolios.cash ) AS total
FROM clients, portfolios
WHERE clients.id = portfolios.client_id
GROUP BY CONCAT(portfolios.id, "-", clients.id)
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Nice solution! I would add there a delimeter: CONCAT(portfolios.id, "-", clients.id). Without delimeter there might be same concatenated value with different value pairs.

Comment: As maksa says, a separator is very important otherwise if you happen to have a situation where portfolio 1 belongs to client 11 (concat: '111') and portfolio 11 belongs to client 1 (concat: also '111') then they're going to be grouped together.

Comment: While `CONCAT` does have a high performance cost, it may well be more performant than using a subquery, as suggested by the other answer...

Comment: There is also `CONCAT_WS('-', field, field)` to concat fields with specified delimiter.

Comment: this is an ingenious solution!