# Display detail data from mysql using group by

Tags: mysql

For example, I have a table:

```
id      name       type           price
123451  Park's Great Hits   Music   19.99
123452  Silly Puddy Toy 3.99
123453  Playstation Toy 89.95
123454  Men's T-Shirt   Clothing    32.50
123455  Blouse  Clothing    34.97
123456  Electronica 2002    Music   3.99
123457  Country Tunes   Music   21.55
123458  Watermelon  Food    8.73
```

If I want to select the cheapest price by type, I use this :

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection

$query = "SELECT type, MIN(price) FROM products GROUP BY type"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "The cheapest  ". $row['type']. " is $" .$row['MIN(price)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Then, it will display:

```
The cheapest Clothing is $32.50
The cheapest Food is $8.73
The cheapest Music is $3.99
The cheapest Toy is $3.99
```

However, I want to know the detail information of the cheapest item so that it will display:

```
    The cheapest Clothing is $32.50 which is Men's T-Shirt and id is 123454
    The cheapest Food is $8.73 which is Watermelon and id is 123458
    The cheapest Music is $3.99 which is Electronica 2002 and id is 123452
    The cheapest Toy is $3.99 which is SillyPuddy and id is 123452
```

Please help!!

Comment: What should be the response when two items of the same type have the lowest price? Will both get displayed?

Comment: See this link will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183373/mysql-group-by-two-columns

Comment: I assume there is a column which is input time, if they are the same cheapest price, display the latest one

Comment: See this link will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183373/mysql-group-by-two-columns

Comment: @red23jordan this time value will be in a separate table?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following query

```
select * from products po
where price = 
(SELECT MIN(price) FROM products pi
where type = po.type)
```

If you want to add a time component (as wirtten in your comments), the query should be

```
select id, name, type, price, time from products po
where price = 
(SELECT MIN(price) FROM products pi1
   where type = po.type)
and time = 
(SELECT MIN(time) FROM products pi2
  where type = po.type
   and price = po.price)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you order first then group you should get what you want:

```
SELECT type, price, name, id FROM products ORDER BY price DESC GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: will it display the minimum price?