# Sql groupby Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have 2 tabl , i want to calculate the number of trips.

```
tbl1
id location
1   A
2   B
3   C

tabl 2
id  tabl1id table1id
1     1       2
2     1       3
3     2       1
4     3       1
5     1       3
6     1       3
```

and i want result like this, I want to count

```
SrNo  A To B   A to C   B To A   C To A
 1     1         3       1         1
```

Comment: and if you have 4 row in tbl1 then there will be 10 column in your desired result. I think you need to change the design...

Comment: thanks for reply @HomayounAfshari basically i want to calculate the total number of trips at specific location. For exampl between A to C location the total number of trips are 3 and A to b the total number of trips are 1.

Comment: how about putting 'A to B', 'A to C', etc to rows instead of columns? In this case you do not need to use dynamic PIVOT queries

Comment: simply use "SELECT src , dest, count(id) FROM tbl2 group by src , dest". then you can join with tbl1 to convert ids to location...

Comment: I would do differently. I would self cross join tbl1 to get a list of all possible directions, and then left joined it with the grouped tbl2 provided by @HomayounAfshari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help u...

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE
(
    id INT , location VARCHAR(1)
)DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE
(
    id INT , tabl1id INT , table1Toid INT
)
INSERT INTO  @tbl1
SELECT  1 ,  'A' UNION ALL
SELECT  2 ,  'B'  UNION ALL
SELECT  3 ,  'C'

INSERT INTO  @tbl2
SELECT      1 ,    1,       2 UNION ALL
    SELECT  2  ,   1  ,     3 UNION ALL
SELECT      3  ,   2  ,     1 UNION ALL
SELECT      4  ,   3  ,     1 UNION ALL
SELECT      5  ,   1   ,    3 UNION ALL
SELECT      6  ,   1   ,    3

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(tabl1id) CNT , (SELECT location FROM @tbl1 WHERE ID=T2.tabl1id)+' To '+(SELECT location FROM @tbl1 WHERE ID=T2.table1Toid) AS location
FROM @tbl2 T2
GROUP BY tabl1id,table1Toid
)D
PIVOT (MIN(CNT) FOR location  IN ([B To A],[C To A],[A To B],[A To C])) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is no matter to see results in rows (instead of columns) you can do this by grouping by two column :

```
SELECT src , dest, count(id) 
FROM tbl2 
GROUP BY src , dest
```

for more see [MySQL GROUP BY two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183373/mysql-group-by-two-columns)